# Agora cloud recording returns 404

Tags: agora.io

I am trying to use rest apis for cloud recording from agora

- Acquire api working fine
- Start api working fine

but query api is returning me

```
{
            "resourceId": "nUwUbQf9Zg6tsgtLslGnDg0lk8RYaUE09pqOuSIgwfwoTqpfJ2tw6vZBJQTihhScR-c4d2ArswXWeE_HpqcfMyVkJzU6WQFVcZT7nOO5DiZpQjPfNd4XpjqVsZH5FrepttBahXeyhmDPqjnbp2eftzQgsBIqDbREHAyS6O2q3bo3JzQMdir1NaCCkQIfXvXwB7Ogtkes2nflOX1Q9ykt-4IcqJvrEU41ilSkR5U-zV3PfpuN5rN3clMJCOI1Ya_VwqqK-KEjlLV_9BAeeaiQnlaEJtCpu88_xHLtKeFIeXVKtrBdAEOfychQI2NYSo8w",
            "sid": "99fe567c724ccc1aa4cbff997f2ea035",
            "code": 404
}
```

My start request was

```
    {
     "uid": uid,
            "cname": Cname,
            "token" : RTCToken,
            "clientRequest": {
                "storageConfig": {
                    "secretKey": SECRET_KEY,
                    "region": REGION,
                    "accessKey": ACCESS_KEY,
                    "bucket": BUCKET,
                    "vendor": VENDOR,
                },
                "recordingConfig": {
                    "audioProfile": 0,
                    "channelType": 0,
                    "maxIdleTime": 30,
                    "transcodingConfig": {
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 360,
                        "fps": 15,
                        "bitrate": 600,
                        "mixedVideoLayout": 2,
                        "backgroundColor": "#fff000",
                        
                    },
                },
            },
        }
```

Comment: Same as for me. Did you fix it?

Comment: yes I have fixed it.
In my case I am sending wrong RTCToken. RTCToken should be generated with uid which we are sending in request not users uid. also this uid should be different from users uid

Comment: Thanks. mine is related to rtc token :)